# Post a file from codebehind

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, sitecore

I want to upload a file from codebehind.

I would like to explain my situation a bit.

My existing code is..

I have a fileupload control.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fuSRForm" runat="server" class="file"/>
```

Then from the codebehind, I check the conditions for that control.

```
if (fuSRForm.HasFile && (fuSRForm.PostedFile.ContentType.ToString().Trim().ToLower().Contains("pdf") || fuSRForm.PostedFile.ContentType.ToString().Trim().ToLower().Contains("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document") || fuSRForm.PostedFile.ContentType.ToString().Trim().ToLower().Contains("msword")))
```

And if the conditions are met,

I used the Sitecore API to upload the file.

This is the part of uploading API.

```
                        // creating necessary arguments to be passed to the processor
                        UploadArgs args = new UploadArgs();

                        // adding http files collection
                        args.Files = base.Request.Files;
```

So, the API is grabbing all posted files by using `base.Request.Files`

---

My new situation is that I creat a pdf file when the user click `Submit`.

Then I save it in a folder named `asyncupload`

After that I have to upload it to `Sitecore` using the same API

So, I tried to change the `base.Request.Files` to my file.

But I am unable to change that.

So, I will have to upload my file using `FileUpload` control.

```
            FileUpload tempFU = new FileUpload();
            tempFU.PostedFile= ????
            args.Files = base.Request.Files;
```

I am stuck right here. I can either post my file from code behind or change the `base.Request.Files` to my file.

either way, I am stuck. Anyone can solve that?

Comment: I'm a little confused about what the end goal here is.  You have a FileUpload control, which implies that the user is uploading a file.  Why then are you "uploading" it again?  That makes no sense to me... it's already on the server, where would you be uploading it to?  Are you going to create a Media Library item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your end goal here is. Maybe you could post some more code if I've understood you incorrectly. But here's how to add a file to the Media Library: [Brian Pedersen: Adding a file to the Sitecore Media Library programatically](http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2009/07/09/adding-a-file-to-the-sitecore-media-library-programatically/)

If you are using an `<asp:FileUpload />` control, then you can save the file to server disk like this:

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/"), "upload/tempfile.tmp");
FileUpload1.SaveAs(filePath);
```

Then call the `AddFile` method from the link I provided above:

```
AddFile(filePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use handler in the api you are going to hit and hit it by

`using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
client.UploadFile(Sitecore Handler, FilePath);
                }`